# How to add google OAuth(spring-social-google) to the existing spring project using spring-social?

Tags: spring, oauth, google-oauth, spring-social

I developed spring application with oauth authentication using spring social project. I'm currently able to authenticate using facebook, twitter and linkedin. I would like to also add google authentication using spring-social-google. Its really confusing for me where to add google's connection factory in the existing spring social configuration.

My current spring social application context is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:facebook="http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/facebook"
    xmlns:twitter="http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/twitter"
    xmlns:social="http://www.springframework.org/schema/social"
    xmlns:linkedin="http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/linkedin"
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/facebook http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/spring-social-facebook.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/linkedin http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/spring-social-linkedin.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/twitter http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/spring-social-twitter.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/social http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/spring-social.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">


    <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/properties/application.properties" />

    <facebook:config app-id="${facebook.clientId}" app-secret="${facebook.clientSecret}" app-namespace="my-app" />
    <twitter:config app-id="${twitter.consumerKey}" app-secret="${twitter.consumerSecret}"/>
    <linkedin:config app-id="${linkedin.consumerKey}" app-secret="${linkedin.consumerSecret}"/>

    <social:jdbc-connection-repository/>    
    <bean id="userIdSource" class="org.springframework.social.security.AuthenticationNameUserIdSource" />

    <bean id="connectController" class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController" autowire="constructor">
        <property name="connectInterceptors">
            <list>
                <bean class="com.prs.ony.controller.facebook.PostToWallAfterConnectInterceptor" />
                <bean class="com.prs.ony.controller.twitter.TweetAfterConnectInterceptor" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="psc" class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ProviderSignInController" autowire="constructor" />        
    <bean id="signInAdapter" class="com.prs.ony.controller.signin.SimpleSignInAdapter" autowire="constructor" />

    <!-- <bean id="disconnectController" class="org.springframework.social.facebook.web.DisconnectController" 
        c:_0-ref="usersConnectionRepository" c:_1="${facebook.clientSecret}" /> -->

</beans>
```

Now im confused where to add the googles connection factory. It has to work along with the existing there oauth providers.

```
<bean id="connectionFactoryLocator" class="org.springframework.social.connect.support.ConnectionFactoryRegistry">
    <property name="connectionFactories">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.social.google.connect.GoogleConnectionFactory">
                <constructor-arg value="${google.consumerKey}" />
                <constructor-arg value="${google.consumerSecret}" />                
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever get this working ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to omit the usage of the concrete social configuration namespace and register connection factories all together:

```
<bean id="connectionFactoryLocator" class="org.springframework.social.connect.support.ConnectionFactoryRegistry">
    <property name="connectionFactories">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory">
                <constructor-arg name="appId" value="${facebook.clientId}" />
                <constructor-arg name="appSecret" value="${facebook.clientSecret}" />
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.social.twitter.connect.TwitterConnectionFactory">
                <constructor-arg name="consumerKey" value="${twitter.consumerKey}" />
                <constructor-arg name="consumerSecret" value="${twitter.consumerSecret}" />
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.social.linkedin.connect.LinkedInConnectionFactory">
                <constructor-arg name="consumerKey" value="${linkedin.consumerKey}" />
                <constructor-arg name="consumerSecret" value="${linkedin.consumerSecret}" />
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.social.google.connect.GoogleConnectionFactory">
                <constructor-arg name="clientId" value="${google.consumerKey}" />
                <constructor-arg name="clientSecret" value="${google.consumerSecret}" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```